# mininet-wifi graphs not workings

Tags: python, linux, mininet

i had installed the latest mininet-wifi

```
sudo mn --version
```

2.5

and when i try to execute any example that have graphical interface like **vanet.py** and **mobility.py ** it shows that error (the examples that doesn't have graphs works fine like **adhoc.py** and **sumo-vanet.py**)

```
root@mypc:/home/mypc/mininet-wifi/examples# python3 vanet.py 
.
.
.
*** Running CLI
*** Starting CLI:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vanet.py", line 74, in <module>
    topology(sys.argv)
  File "vanet.py", line 66, in topology
    CLI(net)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mininet_wifi-2.5-py3.8.egg/mn_wifi/cli.py", line 12, in __init__
    MN_CLI.__init__(self, mn_wifi, stdin=sys.stdin, script=script)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mininet/cli.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.initReadline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mininet/cli.py", line 90, in initReadline
    read_history_file( history_path )
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 155, in __draw_idle_agg
    self.draw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 127, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasQTAggBase, self).draw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 433, in draw
    toolbar.set_cursor(toolbar._lastCursor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 702, in set_cursor
    self.canvas.setCursor(cursord[cursor])
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type FigureCanvasQTAgg has been deleted

(process:414419): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:24:25.081: g_main_context_pop_thread_default: assertion 'stack != NULL' failed
QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
root@mypc:/home/mypc/mininet-wifi/examples#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something wrong with the path of the history_file i just changed the path in **/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mininet/cli.py** to

```
history_path = os.path.expanduser( '/home/mypc/mininet_history' )
```

and it worked .